# PHP Regex 2 words per group

Tags: php, regex

I've been wondering, is it possible to group every 2 words using regex? For 1 word i use this:

`((?:\w'|\w|-)+)`

This works great. But i need it for 2 (or even more words later on).

But if I use this one:

`((?:\w'|\w|-)+) ((?:\w'|\w|-)+)` it will make groups of 2 but not really how i want it. And when it encounters a special char it will start over.

Let me give you an example:

If I use it on this text: `This is an . example text using & my / Regex expression`

It will make groups of 

`This is
example text
regex expression`

and i want groups like this:

`This is
is an
an example
example text
text using
using my
my regex
regex expression`

It is okay if it resets after a . So that it won't match `hello . guys` together for example.

Is this even possible to accomplish? I've just started experimenting with RegEx so i don't quite know the possibilities with this.

If this isn't possible could you point me in a direction that I should take with my problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why would you do this with a regexp? collect the words, then create the pairs...

Comment: 1+2, 2+3, 3+4 ... it's just a simple loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$samp = "This is an . example text using & my / Regex expression";

//removes anything other than alphabets
$samp = preg_replace('/[^A-Z ]/i', "", $samp);

//removes extra spaces
$samp = str_replace("  "," ",$samp);

//the following code splits the sentence into words
$jk = explode(" ",$samp);

$i = sizeof($jk);
$j = 0;

//this combines words in desired format
$array="";
for($j=0;$j<$i-1;$j++)
{
    $array[] = $jk[$j]." ".$jk[$j+1];
}

print_r($array);
```

[`Demo`](http://3v4l.org/gSfLk)

**EDIT**

for your question

> I've changed the regex like this: "/[^A-Z0-9-' ]/i" so it doesn't
>   mess up words like 'you're' and '9-year-old' for example. But by doing
>   this when there is a seperate - or ' in my text, it will treat those
>   as a seperate words. I know why it does this but is it preventable?

change the regex like this

```
preg_replace('/[^A-Z0-9 ]+[^A-Z0-9\'-]/i', "", $samp)
```

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/VC3H6)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! But for example if a text has a year like '1994'? How could I make it so that it doesn't delete numbers? Or for example '9-year-old' will result in 'yearold'. It doesn't have to 'remove' - or ' because words like in this example, or 'you're' for example don't have to get shortened.

Comment: then change regex like this `/[^A-Z0-9 -]/i`

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I've changed the regex like this: `"/[^A-Z0-9-' ]/i"` so it doesn't mess up words like 'you're' and '9-year-old' for example. But by doing this when there is a seperate - or ' in my text, it will treat those as a seperate words. I know why it does this but is it preventable?

Comment: yes preventable.but i am not quite sure about the correct regex. Maybe you could post this one as new question or you could find this previously answered in SO. What you need to do is little bit search.

Comment: Yes alright! you've so much help already! I think i can manage from here on forth. Thanks again :)

Comment: @DejaVu for a note, regex you used `/[^A-Z0-9-' ]/i` is wrong, correct one is `/[^A-Z0-9-\' ]/i` you need to escape the quotes in regex

Comment: Alright, thanks i'll change it! Btw when i want to make group of 3 words and change the $array[] to this: `$array[] = $jk[$j]." ".$jk[$j+1]." ".$jk[$j+2];`. (i don't know if this is the proper way) it gives me this error: `Notice: Undefined offset: 9` I know why it gives me this error. Because it wants to group 3 words while there aren't enough words left to group them. Do you happen to know a quick fix for this or should i just leave this be and don't use 3 group words?

Comment: @DejaVu change limit in for loop from `$j<$i-1` to `$j<$i-2`

Answer (score 2):

Regex is an overkill for this. Simply collect the words, then create the pairs:

```
$a = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four');

$pairs = array();
$prev = null;
foreach($a as $word) {
    if ($prev !== null) {
        $pairs[] = "$prev $word";
    }
    $prev = $word;
}
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/8dqAkz

Comment: Why too much complication. you can use for loop and do simply like [this](http://3v4l.org/skUv5)

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer! I've accepted @krishna 's answer because i found it a bit easier to follow. Gave you a +1 though.

Answer (score 0):

First, strip out non-word characters (replace `\W` with `''`) Then perform your match. Many problems can be made simpler by breaking them down. Regexes are no exception.

Alternatively, strip out non-word characters, condense whitespace into single spaces, then use `explode` on space and `array_chunk` to group your words into pairs.